# ROW_NUMBER not giving me the correct output

Tags: mysql, row-number

I am having some trouble getting the correct row number in my SQL output. I am using the `ROW_NUMBER` function then partitioning by the `ID` and the `date` but nothing seems to be giving me the expected result.

```
SELECT 
    BCG.BudgetId
    ,CAST(BCG.StartOfPeriod AS DATE) AS StartOfPeriod
    ,ROUND(SUM(BCG.Charge),2) AS ExpenditureBudget
    ,ROUND(SUM(BCG.Consumption),2) AS ConsumptionBudget
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY BCG.BudgetId,BCG.StartOfPeriod ORDER BY BCG.StartOfPeriod ASC) AS rowNum
FROM B_BudgetCalGroup BCG 
WHERE BCG.BudgetId = 4940
GROUP BY BCG.BudgetId,StartOfPeriod
```

Current Output:

```
4940    2021-08-01  281495.36   2962365.8   1
4940    2021-09-01  276476.49   2943250.2   1
4940    2021-10-01  303252.47   3143659.7   1
4940    2021-11-01  292298.37   3090468.5   1
4940    2021-12-01  268543.23   2824347.8   1
```

Expected Output:

```
4940    2021-08-01  281495.36   2962365.8   1
4940    2021-09-01  276476.49   2943250.2   2
4940    2021-10-01  303252.47   3143659.7   3
4940    2021-11-01  292298.37   3090468.5   4
4940    2021-12-01  268543.23   2824347.8   5
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because of:

```
 PARTITION BY BCG.BudgetId,BCG.StartOfPeriod
```

This will reset the row number whenever the `StartOfPeriod` is different, which is your case. So replace with:

```
 PARTITION BY BCG.BudgetId
```

Hint: there should never be a reason to have the same field appear in the `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY` part of an `OVER` clause.